# fix ion-search bar postion at top

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

In my ionic 4 app , I have a search or filter the users for list using ion-searchbar . but if I scroll the list ion-searchbar also moving with list. can we fix the ion-searchbar postion fix at top with out writting any css(do we have any in built property).

Answer (score 4):

you can put into a header like.

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-searchbar></ion-searchbar>
</ion-header>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve that using list item divider if it suits your use case:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item-divider sticky style="border: 0">
      <ion-searchbar></ion-searchbar>
    </ion-item-divider>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ,9,10,11]">I am item #{{item}}</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

In short this will keep your search bar in the view while the list can be scrolled across.

Another way (and I think more proper) is to add it to header or footer.